# Control scroll to zoom in and out not working for some applications, ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mouse, mouse-scroll, zooming

While using ubuntu 20.04, control key + scroll(mouse middle button) doesn't work for some applications. It just scrolls down the pdf file, for example. How can I explicitly set ctrl + scroll to zoom in/out?

Comment: Should work by default in the default PDF viewer Evince.

Comment: @vanadium It's not working ;( It just scrolls down/up. When I open the pdf with chrome, it's working.